# localtime_s in c++ using microsoft visual studio 2013

Tags: localtime

Why i get an error enter my coding like this ?

```
void register_acc(int &ar_size){
fstream add_acc("Login ID.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);
fstream ic_state("State.txt");

string username, password, cus_name, IC;
string account;
string time_record;
string check_code;
string state;
string check_username;

time_t time_create = time(NULL);
struct tm *time_info;
localtime_s(time_info, &time_create);
```

The error show : error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'time_info' used

Answer (score 3):

You need to use this:

```
struct tm time_info;
localtime_s(&time_info, &time_create);
```

The way you have it `time_info` points to nothing. You need to allocate space for a `struct tm` and pass a pointer to that to `localtime_s`.